# @Repository and @RestController together

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, restful-url

I have a working JpaRepository as an interface, and a working Restcontroller.

They are two types currently and I like to join them to one!

This is what i have:

```
@Repository
@RestController("problem")
public interface ProblemsController extends JpaRepository<Problem, Integer> {

  @RequestMapping(value = "all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  List<Problem> findAll();
}
```

But when i call http://localhost:8080/application/problem/all I get a 404.

What to do?

Comment: did you try with  @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Also i think is a typo but you wrote applicatioin not application

Comment: @Peter Rader have a look at my solution

Comment: FWIW JPARepository != JPA API. Tags fixed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an XY problem and promotes bad architecture.

Comment: Why not to put the whole application into one source file?

Comment: @xenteros I hope one-sourcefile-app is a joke.

Comment: @PeterRader you started this game :)

Comment: @xenteros Why is it bad architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use this way..but am not get what exactly your are expecting.**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

This is act as a Repositry and REST web service.

**if you got an error. You can check UI page is prperly locating this interface or Not**

Comment: you can select the answer if it helped. click Little tick below downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding / to your RequestMapping not at @RestController

```
 @Repository
 @RestController
 public interface ProblemsController extends JpaRepository<Problem, 
 Integer> {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/problem/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  List<Problem> findAll();
 }
```

**Or you can try this:**

```
    @Repository
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/problem")
    public interface ProblemsController extends JpaRepository<Problem,
                Integer> {

            @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            List<Problem> findAll();
     }
```